# Yeoman auto-load models

Tags: model, ember.js, autoload, yeoman

Is it possible to load every file in `app/scripts/models` directory automatically or do I have to reference every single file in index.html?

I want to have a model-per-file for my Ember app and that would make a lot of lines. Don't want to write redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, and if you are using yeoman (at the last version) and you have generated an `ember.js` app with:

```
yo ember:all
```

you should have a `app.js` in `myproject/scripts/app.js`, where inside the file at the top (somewhere starting from line 10) you have this code lines **which are commented**:

```
require('app/scripts/routes/*');
require('app/scripts/controllers/*');
require('app/scripts/models/*');
require('app/scripts/views/*');
```

**uncomment** them and the build process should be able to pickup your single model files and also other files like views, controllers etc. you have in the directories specified above.

**Update**

It's also worth mentioning that responsible for the `require` statement is the grunt module [`grunt-neuter`](https://github.com/trek/grunt-neuter), so you should have it also defined as a dependency in your `Gruntfile.js`

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are no such lines. If I try to add them manually, JS complains there's no such function as require. Note that I'm using coffeescript, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: do you have the last yeoman version (1.0 beta) and did you build generate your project with the command mentioned above (which you get by installing the `generator-ember` https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember)?

Comment: Yes I have `yo@1.0.0-beta.7` and `generator-ember` and did it the way you described. Strange.

Comment: yes strange, because see here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/blob/master/app/templates/scripts/app.js this is the file the `generator-ember` uses for the generated `app.js` and in the case younare using coffescript it's this file: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/blob/master/app/templates/coffeeScript/app.coffee